# Multiple Buttons, But only one pressed at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've been looking through the site and I've been unable to find anything that answers my question. In my app i have a modal dialog that displays a UICollectionView that uses a custom cell and only contains a UIButton.

I have set the buttons up to be selectable rather than single click. I want to only allow a single button to be selected at a time and when a button is selected I want the other buttons in that section to be disabled. I'm not sure how to go about this as I am still fairly new to IOS. The screen shot below shows the basic appearance of the model and the buttons.

At the moment I can select multiple buttons but I need it to be single selection and when one button is selected the rest are disabled. For the moment I hand the selected in the class for my custom UICollectionViewCell and I have included it below. Any help and suggestions would be great i just need pointing in the right direction.

```
- (IBAction)Selected:(id)sender {
    if(_Button.selected == 0)
    {
        [_Button setSelected:YES];        
    }
    else
    {
        [_Button setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set exclusive touch to all buttons-
[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];

Comment: @developer I tried that, i looped through all the visible cells in the collection view to access the button and setExclusiveTouch to yes but its still multi-select sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In collection view datasource method 
`- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` when you are configuring the cell, set the indexPath item value as tag of the corresponding button in the cell.

Then maintain a property say, `previousSelectedButtonIndex` in which you can maintain the value of the previously selected index.

In your button click handler, if `previousSelectedButtonIndex` contains a value, and if yes, deselect that button, select new button and set `previousSelectedButtonIndex` to the new value.

Please note, you might have to do some error handling, but basically this is how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Declare one global variable as

```
NSInteger selectedIndex;
```

also set -1 value to `selectedIndex` as initially no button is selected.

```
selectedIndex = -1;
```

Then write in datasource method of `UICollectionView`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    //here create cell object of UICollectionViewCell
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
    {
      //show this button as selected by setting different name/color/image for button
       cell.button.enabled = TRUE;
    }
    else
       cell.button.enabled = FALSE;
    return cell;
}


- (void) buttonPressed:(id)sender
  {
    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    if(selectedIndex == selectedButton.tag)
        selectedIndex = -1; //deselect the selected button
    else
        selectedIndex = selectedButton.tag; //select the tapped button
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a collection of buttons. Apple have given the ability to control a series of buttons at the same time. Try reading this to get an idea on how you can achieve this. [Outlet Collections](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html)